# variable from class to class

Tags: vb.net, class

this is my first VB code so be kind :)

I can't get variable named `station_num` from class named `Pinger` to class `StationsIdentifier`
I'm getting error "'station_num' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level"

this is the code:

```
Public Class Pinger

    Public Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtStation.KeyPress
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then '/ When ENTER key is pressed
            Dim temp, pinger_file_name As String   ' save names for variable
            Dim station_num As String
            station_num = txtStation.Text                       ' set station number from text specified in text box
            temp = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("temp")   ' get TEMP variable from system
            pinger_file_name = temp + "\Pinger.txt"             ' set TEMP FILE NAME with full path

            If System.IO.File.Exists(pinger_file_name) = True Then  ' check if file exist
                System.IO.File.Delete(pinger_file_name)             ' delete file
            End If

            'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100000)              ' sleep
            Dim oWrite As System.IO.StreamWriter
            oWrite = IO.File.CreateText(pinger_file_name)
            oWrite.WriteLine(station_num)
            oWrite.Close()

            Call StationsIdentifier.FindStation()
        End If

    End Sub



    Public Sub PingButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PingButton.Click
        Dim temp, pinger_file_name As String   ' save names for variable
        Dim station_num As String
        station_num = txtStation.Text                       ' set station number from text specified in text box
        temp = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("temp")   ' get TEMP variable from system
        pinger_file_name = temp + "\Pinger.txt"             ' set TEMP FILE NAME with full path

        If System.IO.File.Exists(pinger_file_name) = True Then  ' check if file exist
            System.IO.File.Delete(pinger_file_name)             ' delete file
        End If

        'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100000)              ' sleep
        Dim oWrite As System.IO.StreamWriter
        oWrite = IO.File.CreateText(pinger_file_name)
        oWrite.WriteLine(station_num)
        oWrite.Close()

        Call StationsIdentifier.FindStation()
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class StationsIdentifier

    Shared Sub FindStation()

        MsgBox("station number is:" + station_num)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `StationIdentifier` class `Shared Sub FindStation` you try to access the variable `station_num`, but that variable is not declared in that function or in that class.

I assume you mean to pass a `station_num` in to the find function...

```
 Shared Sub FindStation(ByVal station_num As String)
     ' Do stuff to find the station here
 End Sub
```

Comment: I added `(ByVal station_num As String)` and now the `Call StationsIdentifier.FindStation` is delivered another error:`Argument not specified for parameter 'station_num' of 'Public Shared Sub FindStation(station_num As String)`

Comment: Yeah, you have to pass a value to the function now.